# Can't create App Store Provisioning Profile for AppStore-Distribution

Tags: xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

As a company we enrolled successfully the Apple Enterprise Developer Program. As shown in the screenshot below, Apple wrotes

*"Get everything you need to develop and distribute your apps on the App Store."*

[image]

**Enterprise Account:**

But when we want to create a provisioning profile for distributing to the App Store, there is no useful action for it. We are only allowed to distribute as InHouse and AdHoc. "App Store" is missing here:

[image]

**Personal Developer Account:**

Only when i login into the Apple Member Center with my personal developer account, which is NOT an Enterprise Account and which doesn't belong to the company i work for, i can select "App Store" in the Distribution section:

[image]

How can we archive to distribute to the app store next to AdHoc distribution and next to InHouse Distribution?

I also tried to enroll the normal Developer Program, but we are not allowed to since we are already member of the Enterprise Developer Program. As seen in the first Screenshot above, there is no way to sign another program than the Enterprise Program.

***U P D A T E***

We now tried to sign the iOS Developer Company Programm. These are steps:

I just followed your link.

1. I clicked at "iOS Developer Programm Company 99$" at [this site](https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/).
2. Next Screen: "iOS Developer Programm" Click on Button "Enroll now 99$"
3. "Enrolling in Apple Developer Programs" -> "Continue"
4. "Sign in or create an Apple ID." -> "Existing Apple ID" -> "Continue"
5. "Are you enrolling as an individual or organization?" -> "Company"
6. I end up at the second screen in the question.

Comment: Yes, we signed the developer program with a completely new apple-id. Thank you very much for your help! It's so crazy that apple isn't able to support multiple programs on the same apple-id (or at least replace the new one with the old one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the Enterprise Program doesn't let you put apps into the normal App Store. It's only for in-house apps. At least that's what my research concluded when my company was looking at ways to deploy apps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We afraid that too in between. But how can we get a AppStore-valid Developer Programm, now after we have the enterprise program.   As seen in the first screenshot of my question we're not able to do that since we are enterprise.

Answer (score 3):

An Enterprise Account only allows you to distribute in-house within your company which is what you signed up for unfortunately. What you want is a [Company Developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/which-program/) account which will allow you to still maintain multiple developers AND deploy to the app store. You will have to supply your DUNS information again, etc. It is the same price as an individual account ($99US)

EDIT

Based on our conversation below you will have to enroll into the Company program with an AppleID other than the Agent account AppleID you just burned on the Enterprise account.

Comment: Do we have to create a new AppleID for signing the Company Developer Account? I tried your link to enroll this type of Account. But i am not allowed to. The Process stucks at the second Screenshot in my Question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sq6O.png

I think it is because we already signed the enterprise account.

Comment: Are you clicking Enterprise Account again? You want Developer / Company account, not Enterprise.

Comment: I just followed your link. 

1. I clicked at "iOS Developer Programm Company 99$"
2. Next Screen: "iOS Developre Programm" Click on Button "Enroll now 99$"
3. "Enrolling in Apple Developer Programs" -> "Continue"
4. "Sign in or create an Apple ID." -> "Existing Apple ID" -> "Continue"
5. "Are you enrolling as an individual or organization?" -> "Company"
6. I end up at the screen in my first comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sq6O.png

It drives me crazy ...

Comment: You very well may need to use an alternate AppleID. What's "funny" is when I go into my Enterprise account I see the same message you do despite the fact I know it has zero ability to submit to the App Store. When my company went through the same motions we did it backwards to what you just encountered and did in fact had to create a new AppleID. Apple gets really quirky about Agent accounts overlapping between programs.